# indexedDB read inconsistency

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am trying indexedDB for the first time, trying to follow various examples I found on the Internet. It works, somewhat, but I am getting inconsistent results when I read the database.

The database is created as follows:

```
myapp.indexedDB.open = function() {
    var request = indexedDB.open('todos', "2");

    request.onblocked = function(e) {
        alert('Please close all other tabs with this site open so the database can be updated.');
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        myapp.indexedDB.db = e.target.result;
        myapp.indexedDB.db.onversionchange = function(e) {
            myapp.indexedDB.db.close();
            alert('The database is being upgraded. Please reload.');
        };
        myapp.indexedDB.getAllTodoItems();
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
        var db = e.target.result;

        if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains('todo')) {
            var store = e.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
                'todo',
                {keyPath: "timeStamp"}
            );
        }

        if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains('sites')) {
            var site_store = e.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
                'sites',
                {keyPath: 'id'}
            );
        }
    };
    request.onfailure = myapp.indexedDB.onerror;
};
```

The todo store is from an example I found. It is the sites store that I am having difficulty with.

I read the sites store like this:

```
function update_sites() {
    $('#sites_table').ig_grid('delete_all_rows');
    var db = myapp.indexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(["sites"], "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore('sites');

    var cursorRequest = store.openCursor();

    cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var result = e.target.result;
        if(!!result == false) return;

        render_site(result.value);
        console.log('rendered a site');
        result.continue();
    };

    cursorRequest.onerror = myapp.indexedDB.onerror;
}

function render_site(site) {
    $('#sites_table').ig_grid('add_row', [site.id,site.id,site.flag,site.site_code,site.site_name,site.owner_name,site.address,site.hive_capacity,site.hive_count,render_status(site.status_id)]);
}
```

So far, all is well. Data written to the database is read and rendered correctly.

The problem occurs when I update the database. The update is done like this:

```
function sync_sites() {
    display_status('');
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type:   "GET",
        url:    '/myapp.pl/REST/sites'
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        display_status(jqXHR.responseText);
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var sites = jQuery.parseJSON(data.data);
        for (var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
            myapp.indexedDB.add_site(sites[i]);
        }
        alert('sync done');
    });
}

myapp.indexedDB.add_site = function(site) {
    var db = myapp.indexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(["sites"], "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore('sites');
    var request = store.put(site);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        // TODO: whatever is appropriate if the site is added successfully
    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log(e.value);
    };
};
```

The update of the database also succeeds.

The problem is that shortly after the update of the database begins - just after the 'sync done' alert is displayed, the update_sites function empties the displayed table of sites and does not add any sites: as if the database were empty. Then, if I keep reloading the sites display, after a few more seconds (several reloads) several hundreds to a few thousand rows are added to the sites table, with each row duplicated several times. There are actually 216 records in the sites store/table normally. Eventually, about the time the last database update (put) completes (I think) the display update works correctly again.

The display update (update_sites) works correctly most of the time - it only gives incorrect results if I run it in a short interval of a few seconds after sync_sites has run.

There are two error modes: in the first, no data is read from the store, as if it were empty or the cursor matched no records (never succeeded); and in the second the cursor does not stop after all records in the store have been returned, it keeps looping through all the records over and over, until it eventually stops at some seemingly arbitrary point.

I don't see any errors in the error console, either when update_sites runs correctly or when it gives incorrect results, or from sync_sites. In fact, no errors or warnings at all in the error console when this is running.

I have inspected the underlying database with sqlite3 and there is no duplication of records in the database that I can see. There are 219 records in object_data: 3 related to the todo store and 216 related to the sites store.

FWIW, this is with Firefox 16.0.1.

Am I doing something wrong?

Are there additional errors, warnings, traces or diagnostics I can enable that might help to pinpoint the cause of the errors?

Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 3):

Due to async nature of IndexedAPI `alert('sync done');` is incorrect, because IDBRequest `onsuccess` handler do not mean it is successfully added. Only `oncompeleted` handler of IDBTransaction ensure it was added and ready for quering the record.

Additionally you should use single transaction to store the record. `myapp.indexedDB.add_site` should be `myapp.indexedDB.add_sites(sites, callback)` so that it loop and put the record in one go. When `oncompeleted` it invokes callback.

Edit: add add_sites function.

```
myapp.indexedDB.add_sites = function(sites, callback) {
  var db = myapp.indexedDB.db;
  var trans = db.transaction(["sites"], "readwrite");
  trans.oncompleted = callback;
  var store = trans.objectStore('sites');

  var put = function(i) {
    var request = store.put(sites[i]);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      i--;
      if (i >= 0) put(i);    
    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e.value);
    };
  };

  put(sites.length - 1);
};
```

Comment: I appreciate that the database updates are not complete when alert('sync done') is called. In fact, I think the store updates are not even started at that point, due to the nature of javascript. I don't understand your point about using a single transaction to store the record.

Comment: the alert('sync done') will be called when you iterated all the sites that came back from your xhr result. But this doesn't mean the sites are stored because all db transactions are done async. The reason why Kyaw uses only one transaction has several reasons. 1. opening a transaction every time has a certain cost of CPU (bad for performance). 2. Opening a write transaction over and over again for the same objectstore may lead to locks and transaction will have to wait. (bad for performance) 3. You can now use the oncomplete callback to be certain all inserts are done.

Comment: Oh! Thanks Kristof and Kyaw - now I get it!! That's a very good point. The update is rather slow the way I did it. But, as much as what I did was poor in several respects, I still don't understand why it causes incorrect read results rather than just poor performance.

Comment: I still don't understand why it causes incorrect > 
Think about transaction.

Comment: Are you saying that indexedDB does not support multiple concurrent transactions? Given its asynchronous API that's a rather severe handicap. While I can appreciate that it might be ambiguous whether one transaction reads state as it was before or as it is during some other concurrent transaction, I don't expect at all that an update in one transactions causes complete incorrect results in another.

Comment: No, multiple concurrent transaction are fine. In fact, your transactions are running parallel (possibly out of order).

Comment: Why should it result in incorrect results. I think there are 2 things. First issue: no results while reading: I think in this case you where calling the read function while you where inserting data. This is logical. I would want to read data from a transaction that isn't commited yet. If that transaction would go wrong you would have a real inconsistency. This means if it is the first time you are populating your db, you must call the read when the transaction is completed. Second issue: If you don't provide a filter, all data from the object store will be retrieved. In your case 216 stores

Comment: Issue 3: "Then, if I keep reloading the sites display, after a few more seconds (several reloads) several hundreds to a few thousand rows are added to the sites table, with each row duplicated several times. " Are you sure you aren't calling the update_sites() method multiple times?

Comment: I am quite certain only one execution of update_sites() at a time.